# JQuery scrollbar component for Desktop browsers and iOS & Android

Tags: jquery, android, ios, scrollbar

I have been stuck with this problem and unable to find the working solution.

I am using DIV to show the content (images...form elements etc) within tables.

I would like to add scrollbar to the DIV so if content is going out of the DIV it should be scrollable. I tried several libraries/components without success. None of them are working for all environments.

1. http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/uscrollbar
   fails to display scrollbar and also make the content to disappear.
2. jScrollTouch_v2.0.js
   Does on work on Android
3. http://www.baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/
   It just fails to work. Start to throw errors.

Please suggest any library to solve this problem

Comment: What are the error tinyscrollbar trows. It should work on every platform.

Answer (score 0):

[iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll) should help

Comment: You should take time to read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer

Comment: Thanks sheR Oktamych. I will check this out and post my findings.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.